# Xamarin.iOS Can’t control iOS Activity Indicator from WebView Navigating and Navigated events

Tags: webview, xamarin.ios, navigation

I have a ContentPage that has a WebView and an ActivityIndicator. There are event handlers for the Navigating and Navigated events to activate and de-activate the ActivityIndicator. On iOS, the Navigating event fires, but the Navigated event does not fire consistently. This often leaves the ActivityIndicator in a perpetually activated state. This can be reproduced by navigating to https://www.fairfaxcounty.gov/topics/contact-us.

It was suggested that I use a custom web renderer to respond to DidFinishNavigation and DidFailNavigation and send a MessagingCenter message to turn off the activity indicator. I added this and it (mostly) worked, but for whatever reason (possibly the update to XF 5 or change under the covers to WKWebView), it has stopped working. DidFinishNavigation still fires in the custom renderer, but now Navigating and Navigated never fire on the WebView. DidFailNavigation never fires and the pages are rendering completely and correctly, so I don’t believe failed navigation is the issue. If I remove the custom renderer, it’s back to the Navigating event firing and Navigated only firing some of the time.

I would greatly appreciate any insight on this.

```
<ContentPage xmlns = "http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns: x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns: vm = "clr-namespace:FFXPubXam.ViewModels"
                x: Class = "FFXPubXam.Views.WebPage"
                x: Name = "root"
                Shell.NavBarIsVisible = "false" >
    < ContentPage.Content >
        < Grid >
            < WebView x: Name = "WebViewControl"
                        Source = "{Binding Url}"
                        Navigating = "WebViewControl_Navigating"
                        Navigated = "WebViewControl_Navigated" />
            < ActivityIndicator x: Name = "activity"
                                IsRunning = "False"
                                IsEnabled = "False"
                                IsVisible = "False"
                                HeightRequest = "40"
                                WidthRequest = "100"
                                VerticalOptions = "CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions = "CenterAndExpand"
                                Color = "{DynamicResource FFX_Blue4}"
                                BackgroundColor = "Transparent”/>
            </ Grid >
    </ ContentPage.Content >
</ ContentPage >

[QueryProperty("Url", "url")]
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class WebPage : ContentPage
{
    private string baseUrl = string.Empty;
    private bool subscribed = false;

    private string url;

    public string Url
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                url = Uri.UnescapeDataString(value);
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return url;
        }
    }

    public WebPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new WebPageViewModel();
    }

    public WebPage(string arg)
    {
        Url = arg;

        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new WebPageViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        if (baseUrl == string.Empty)
        {
            if (Url != null)
            {
                baseUrl = Url;
            }
        }

        if (WebViewControl.Source?.ToString() != baseUrl)
        {
            WebViewControl.Source = baseUrl;
        }

        base.OnAppearing();

        Logging.Write(LogType.Info, $"OnAppearing: Url={url}");

        if (!subscribed) SubScribe();

        ToggleActivityIndicator(true);
    }

    private void WebViewControl_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        Logging.Write(LogType.Info, $"Navigating: Url={url}");
        ToggleActivityIndicator(true);
    }

    private void WebViewControl_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Logging.Write(LogType.Info, $"Navigated: Url={url}");
        ToggleActivityIndicator(false);
    }

    private void ToggleActivityIndicator(bool state)
    {
        Logging.Write(LogType.Info, $"ToggleActivityIndicator: state={state} stack={new StackTrace()}");
        activity.IsRunning = state;
        activity.IsEnabled = state;
        activity.IsVisible = state;
    }

    private void SubScribe()
    {
        Logging.Write(LogType.Info, $"Subscribe: call stack={new StackTrace()}");

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "End", (sender) =>
        {
            ToggleActivityIndicator(false);
        });
    }
}
    
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace FFXPubXam.iOS.Renderers
{
    class MyDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {
        public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "End");
            Logging.Write(LogType.Info, $"DidFinishNavigation: after Send");
        }
        public override void DidFailNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "End", error.ToString());
        }
    }

    class CustomWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                this.NavigationDelegate = new MyDelegate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the URL you provided under XF5. Even though it took a long time, WebViewControl_Navigated was triggered anyway. I also tested the url "https://stackoverflow.com/", and WebViewControl_Navigated responded quickly.

I'm afraid the root cause of this issue is the website "fairfaxcounty".

Besides, if you want to call "ToggleActivityIndicator" in your custom renderer, the MessagingCenter is not a good choice. You can implement it more efficiently via event.

Define the event in your CustomWebView class:

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public delegate void NavigateDel(bool flag);

    public event NavigateDel NavigateEvent;

    public void CallNavigate(bool flag)
    {
        NavigateEvent(flag);
    }
}
```

Then subscribe to the event in "WebPage":

```
public WebPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new WebPageViewModel();
    WebViewControl.NavigateEvent += ToggleActivityIndicator;
}
```

If you have created a custom renderer, there is no need to subscribe to Navigating and Navigated. To show the Indicator when the page is loading, you also need to override "DidStartProvisionalNavigation".

```
class MyDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    CustomWebView customView;

    public MyDelegate(CustomWebView view)
    {
        customView = view;
    }

    public override void DidStartProvisionalNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        customView.CallNavigate(true);
    }

    public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        customView.CallNavigate(false);
    }
    public override void DidFailNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error)
    {
    }
}

class CustomWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            CustomWebView control = (CustomWebView)Element;
            this.NavigationDelegate = new MyDelegate(control);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. Thank you SO much for take the time to answer!!

Comment: Thanks, @大陸北方網友, this is great. I don't suppose there is a similar approach in Android? The Android WebViewRenderer doesn't have NavigationDelegate so I'm going to try overriding it's WebClient using SetWebViewClient but I want to know if there's a better way.